# Junit test to cover Exception.How to write test case to cover all three exceptions

Tags: java, junit

```
public void enqueue(AlarmMessage alarmMessage) {
   try
{
        if(alarmMessage != null)

     {
        alarmQueue.add(alarmMessage);
        LOGGER.info("Added alarm to queue :"+alarmMessage.getMessage());
      }
     }catch(IllegalStateException le){
            LOGGER.error("Error while enqueue message IllegalStateException ",le);
        }catch(ClassCastException ce){
            LOGGER.error("Error while enqueue message ClassCastException ",ce);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException ie){
            LOGGER.error("Error while enqueue message IllegalArgumentException ",ie);
        }
    }
```

Comment: by writing three tests

Answer (score 0):

Use some mock framework, ie. [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/), and create 3 tests with variously configured instances of alarmQueue mock, that will throw anything you want.
Then just call your enqueue method from those tests.